# How to deploy an existing wordpress project on windows azure

Tags: php, wordpress, deployment, azure

My team now is working on a wordpress project named "trdocs" for our company, we installed wordpress locally and installed lots of plugins and we have our own database, etc. Now we would like to put this existing wordpress project on Windows Azure. We want not only to migrate the project, but also the database on SQL azure also.
Personally, I followed [How to deploy WordPress using the Windows Azure SDK for PHP WordPress scaffold](http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/how-to-deploy-wordpress-using-the-windows-azure-sdk-for-php-wordpress-scaffold#h2Section0)
, it's good post, but it's to deploy a brand new wordpress on Azure. Does any body have any ideas?

Expecting answers...

Regards,
Leona

Answer (score 0):

Actually the same [link](http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/how-to-deploy-wordpress-using-the-windows-azure-sdk-for-php-wordpress-scaffold) above has a section which explains how you can import an existing PHP-Wordpress codebase in your newly created project, as below:

[**Using an existing WordPress codebase**](http://azurephp.interoperabilitybridges.com/articles/how-to-deploy-wordpress-using-the-windows-azure-sdk-for-php-wordpress-scaffold#h2Section6):

If you already have an existing WordPress codebase and would like to move your files into the WordPress scaffold there is a new command line parameter that will allow you to import your existing source instead of downloading a new copy. To use it add the -source parameter, which will be similar to the following

```
-source path/to/WordPress
```

Note: I followed the exact same path, I added the "-source" parameter directing to my existing wordpress folder and when new project was created all my files were imported to new project. This was very easy as I could use SQL Azure immediately which was set in ServiceConfiguration.cscfg befor I ran the WordPress scaffold.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following article http://ben.lobaugh.net/blog/20600/wordpress-how-to-migrate-from-local-development-to-windows-azure

Comment: thank you ben, I've followed your post, and I don't why sometimes when I active a plugin, I always got an error about database problem.And then the whole site will crash...